# 'ORA-01031: insufficient privileges' error received when inserting into a View

Tags: oracle, insert, triggers, package, ora-01031

Under the user name 'MY_ADMIN', I have successfully created a table called 'NOTIFICATIONS' and a view called 'V_NOTIFICATIONS'. On the 'V_NOTIFICATIONS' view I have successfully created a trigger and a package that takes what the user attempts to insert into the view and inserts it into the table. The 'V_NOTIFICATIONS' trigger and package also perform the update and delete functions on the table when the user attempts to perform the update and delete functions on the view.

I have done this with many views in the project I am currently working on, as many views sit over the top of many different tables, however when attempting to insert a record into this view I receive an 'ORA-01031: insufficient privileges' error.

I am able to insert directly into the table using the same code that is in the package, but not into the view. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the requested code:

VIEW: (When the UNION below is commented out, the package runs as expected)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "MY_ADMIN"."V_NOTIFICATIONS" AS
  SELECT N_ID,
    NOTIFICATION_TYPE,
    CASE WHEN NOTIFICATION_DESC = 'C' THEN 'Copy' ELSE 'Send to' END NOTIFICATION_DESC,
    CASE WHEN CONTACT_TYPE = 'D' THEN 'Department' ELSE 'Contact' END CONTACT_TYPE,
    A.AU_USER_ID,
    A.CONTACT_NAME,
    D.DEPARTMENT_ID,
    D.DEPT_DESC
  FROM NOTIFICATIONS AN,
    (SELECT A1.AU_USER_ID,
            AU.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || AU.LAST_NAME CONTACT_NAME
       FROM APP_USERS_CONTACT_INFO A1,
            APPLICATION_USERS AU
      WHERE A1.AU_USER_ID = AU.USER_ID
    /*UNION
     SELECT 0,
            NULL
       FROM DUAL*/) A,
    (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, 
            DESCRIPTION DEPT_DESC
       FROM DEPARTMENTS
      UNION
     SELECT 0 DEPARTMENT_ID,
            NULL DEPT_DESC 
       FROM DUAL) D
  WHERE NVL(AN.AU_USER_ID,0)      = A.AU_USER_ID
    AND NVL(AN.D_DEPARTMENT_ID,0) = D.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

PACKAGE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE NOTIFICATIONS_PKG AS

   PROCEDURE INSERT_NOTIFICATION(P_N_ROW V_NOTIFICATIONS%ROWTYPE);

END NOTIFICATIONS_PKG;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY NOTIFICATIONS_PKG AS

   PROCEDURE INSERT_NOTIFICATION(P_N_ROW V_NOTIFICATIONS%ROWTYPE) IS

    L_NOTIFICATION_DESC    VARCHAR2(1);
    L_CONTACT_TYPE         VARCHAR2(1);

   BEGIN

      CASE P_N_ROW.NOTIFICATION_DESC
        WHEN 'Copy' THEN
          L_NOTIFICATION_DESC := 'C';
        ELSE
          L_NOTIFICATION_DESC := 'S';
      END CASE;

      CASE P_N_ROW.CONTACT_TYPE
        WHEN 'Department' THEN
          L_CONTACT_TYPE := 'D';
        ELSE
          L_CONTACT_TYPE := 'C';
      END CASE;

      INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS VALUES (
      P_N_ROW.N_ID,
      P_N_ROW.NOTIFICATION_TYPE,
      L_NOTIFICATION_DESC,
      L_CONTACT_TYPE,
      NVL(P_N_ROW.AU_USER_ID, 0),
      NVL(P_N_ROW.DEPARTMENT_ID, 0),
      APP_GLOBAL_PKG.GET_AUDIT);

   END INSERT_AGREEMENT_NOTIFICATION;
END AGREEMENT_NOTIFICATIONS_PKG;
```

The trigger is setup just to pass information to this package to insert the row. Upon trying to run the following line of code I receive the ORA-01031 error:

```
INSERT INTO V_AGREEMENT_NOTIFICATIONS VALUES (5781, 'Collateral Request', 'Send to', 'Contact', 797, '797T', 0, null);
```

Comment: is it possible to insert data into a view?  Dont think so.

Comment: you can, but only under certain conditions (for example, the view is not a one-to-many join, or there exists an instead-of-trigger)

Comment: Sounds like over complication to me.  Are you aware that stored procedures encapsulate access, so you could grant execute on insert/update procedures that perform the actions without granting the access to the table?

Comment: The trigger that exists on the 'V_NOTIFICATIONS' view is an instead of insert trigger. Also, I've narrowed this error down to a certain part of the view where I union:
(SELECT DEPT_ID, DEPT_DESC FROM DEPARTMENTS)
with
(SELECT 0 DEPT_ID, null DEPT_DESC FROM DUAL).
Also, whether it's overcomplicated or not this error still seems out of left field.

Comment: Can you run up a demo script.
It's hard to tell whether the 1031 error is coming from the insert, the trigger or the package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The INSERT into the view fails because you can't insert into DUAL.  Not just you, but anybody.  Try

```
INSERT INTO DUAL (DUMMY) VALUES ('1')
```

to see what happens.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand that Oracle would see this as attempting to insert into Dual even though I have the insert rerouted through the trigger.

Comment: @Patrick: I expect that Oracle checks permissions for being able to insert through the view before firing triggers, which makes some sense - no use firing triggers if the user in question doesn't have permissions on the view - but in this case the presence of DUAL messed things up.

Answer (score 1):

"I am able to insert directly into the table using the same code that is in the package, but not into the view."

If you call the package directly (ie not indirectly through a trigger), does it work ?

If it doesn't then you can ignore the view/trigger side of things and concentrate on the package. Generally if you can run the SQL directly but not through a package it is because you have a role granted to your use with the necessary privilege. Stored PL/SQL does not have role privileges.

If it the package does work, then probably the user doesn't have insert privilege on the view. It may be something odd like the trigger doesn't have privileges on the package but that would probably be a compilation error unless it used dynamic SQL.

INVOKER rights on the package may also have an effect, since that would mean that it runs with the privileges of the trigger owner rather than the package owner. The trigger owner is probably the owner of the view, but that may be different from the owner of the table(s).

Comment: When I call the package directly it works.

Also, the MY_ADMIN user (which is the user I am connected as) is the owner of the package, trigger, view, and table, so I should have all privileges as I have granted all privileges to MY_ADMIN.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on MJB's comment to the original post, there are [several requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30:%7E:text=Notes%20on%20Updatable%20Views) (search for "Notes on Updatable Views" at that link) to allow a view to be updatable. A *few* rules from that section:

- All the columns in the view must map to a column of a single table.
- The view cannot have a set operator, `DISTINCT` operator, aggregate or analytic function, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and similar clauses
- If the view contains any joins, the DML must affect only one table

There is an `ALL_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS` data dictionary view that can list the columns of a view that is inherently updatable, that can be updated, inserted, or deleted.

```sql
@dev01> describe ALL_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS
 Name         Null?    Type
 ------------ --------- --------------
 OWNER         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 TABLE_NAME    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 COLUMN_NAME   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 UPDATABLE              VARCHAR2(3)
 INSERTABLE             VARCHAR2(3)
 DELETABLE              VARCHAR2(3)
```